# get data from other filed in odoo

Tags: odoo-9

I need to get value field2 from list values in field1. Field1 is relation many2many with field in another model.
I tried to use domain for it but everytime I received error.

```
class filial_page_products(models.Model):
    gallery_rstamp_products_ids = fields.Many2many('product.template',
                                     'gallery_rstamp_products_rel',
                                     'gallery_rstamp_products_ids', 'filial_page_new_rstamp_products_ids',
                                     'Gallery products')
    default_gallery_product_id =  fields.Many2one('product.template','Default maket', domain="[(default_gallery_product_id, 'in', 'filial_page_gallery_rstamp_products_ids')]")

class product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    filial_page_gallery_rstamp_products_ids = fields.Many2many('product.template',
                                 'gallery_rstamp_products_rel',
                                 'filial_page_recovery_rstamp_products_ids', 'gallery_rstamp_products_ids',
                                 'Gallery list')
    filial_page_default_maket_product_ids = fields.One2many('pr_filials.filial_page_products',
                                                            'default_gallery_product_id',
                                                            'Linked page products')
```

How can I use domain to select only those values that are specified in the gallery_rstamp_products_ids field?
of course, I can set default_gallery_product_id from all products but I don't like it.

Comment: Use onchange method

Answer (score 0):

Your domain doesn't look quite right. The left operand should be quoted and the right side should *not* be quoted (unless it's actually supposed to be evaluated as a string).

```
domain="[('default_gallery_product_id', 'in', filial_page_gallery_rstamp_products_ids)]"
```

Note, there's a special format required for filtering against `x2many` fields (`one2many` or `many2many`). You may need to use this (below), however, there have been [reports of issues using this in newer versions](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/16072).

```
domain="[('default_gallery_product_id', 'in', filial_page_gallery_rstamp_products_ids[0][2])]"
```

Here's some [documentation on domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#domains).